# What is the -m used (or useful) for in setting up virtual environments?

Tags: python, python-venv

I've learned that when setting up a virtual environment to use for python scripts and libraries, it's recommended to first do this in terminal:

```
python3 -m venv venv
```

why is the '-m' needed and where else is it commonly used?

Comment: I believe `-m` ensures that the argument `venv` in this case is run as a module, instead of being ran as python code. I think this means that `__main__.py` will be ran inside of the module `venv`

Comment: Correct; the  module object is executed as the ` __main__` module.

Answer (score 2):

It's about how python finds the module.

[From the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html):

> When called with `-m module-name`, the given module is located on the
>   Python module path and executed as a script.
>
> Since the argument is a module name, you must not give a file
>   extension (.py).

The `-m` flag tells python to search for the module (or package) `venv` in it's own path, not a script in the current directory.

The distinction is important when you try to run a package. There is a big difference between:

`python foo/bar/baz.py`

and

`python -m foo.bar.baz`

In the latter case, foo.bar is imported and relative imports will work correctly with foo.bar as the starting point.